# What happens when an android activity starts another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

wasnt really sure what words to query in google, so im just going to ask this question.

What happens to an activity when i start another activity?

Lets say I am currently on activity A, then from a, i called a function to startService a new intent that opens activity B. What happens to the lifecycle of A? is it destroyed? stopped?

Subquestion. If the activity is paused, how do i call/open it back from the newly started activity?

Comment: Read This offcial Tutorial for this problem [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Activity A is paused, then stopped -  both the `onPause()` & `onStop()` methods are called, but `onDestroy()` is not called. The Activity still remains in the back stack.

*Quoting the Android documentation:*

> #### Activity Lifecycle
>
> *Activities in the system are managed as an activity stack. When a new
> activity is started, it is placed on the top of the stack and becomes
> the running activity -- the previous activity always remains below it
> in the stack, and will not come to the foreground again until the new
> activity exits.*

Comment: @keyser This is a wrong answer. The Activity is not paused, it is stopped. The 'onStop()` is called on the previous Activity when we move from one Activity to another. `onStop()` for Activity A will be called. The link you provided shows that in the diagram you mentioned. I know this is a really old post, but the answer is not correct.